# ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object I'm just trying to get to my edit page this error wont let me

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

on my home.blade.php view

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit') }}" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

i just want to view the edit page when i click this link but an ErrorException occur what could be wrong?

this is my PostController

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post);
    }
```

heres my web.php where all my route is

```
Route::get('posts/home', function () {
    return view('posts/home');
});

Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('about');
});

Route::get('contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::get('posts', function () {
    return view('posts/index');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
//Route::post('posts', 'PostController@store');
Route::post('posts', 'PostController@store')->name('insert');
Route::post('posts', 'PostController@update')->name('update');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostController@create');
```

Comment: please add error message. You have tried to access property of an object that doesn't exists

Comment: what does your edit page look like?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test_project\resources\views\posts\home.blade.php) is this the one you want to check?

Comment: can you share your route coding and controller function?

Comment: Please add edit route

Comment: @kunal i posted the routes can you check please

Comment: @Lestah see my answer and follow instructions that i suggest

Comment: @kunal sory i didn't see that il try

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your route name, it is likey that you are missing a parameter to identify the post to edit.
something like;

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit', ['id'=>$id])}}">foo</a>
```

Comment: it's still the same error  ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

if you performing editing data
Your route is like:-

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/post/edit/{id}', 'PostController@edit');
```

Now your function looks like:-

```
public function edit($id=null){
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.edit')->with(compact('post'));
}
```

Now your anchor tag

```
<a href="{{ url('/post/edit/'.$post->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

You can implement in your case in this above example.
Hope it helps

Comment: thanks but i still get the same error ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: have you change the route and print the id in your function

Comment: i followed all your instruction kunal but i still get the same error sorry

Comment: i added this one Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/post/edit/{id}', 'PostController@edit');

Comment: you are doing something wrong ? can you share your blade file

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.edit', [$posts->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I dont think that you need the rectangular brackets, but it should still be fine `[$posts->id])` -> `$posts->id)`